# EF4 Self-Tracking entities and WCF serialization creates stack overflow

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, serialization, entity-framework-4, self-tracking-entities

I try to get above configuration working, but with no luck.

**Step 1)**

I started a new solution with a *WCF Service Application* project.

**Step 2)**

In this project, I added an edmx file and create a very simple model:
Entity ***Parent*** with *Id* and *DisplayName*
Entity ***Child*** with *Id* and *ChildDisplayName*
Association from *Parent* to *Child*, *1-to-m*, resulting in NavigationProperties on both entities.
I generatedthe database without any problems. After generation, I inserted one *Parent* object with two related *Child* objects manually to the database.

**Step 3)**

I added the code generation, using the ***ADO.NET Self-Tracking Entity Generator***.
I know that this should be done in diffrent assemblies, but to make it straight and easy, I put it all to the same project (the WCF project)

**Step 4)**

I just changed the IService Interface to create a simple get

```
    [OperationContract]
    Parent GetRootData(Int32 Id);
```

In the corresponding implementation, I take an *Page* object from the context and return it:

```
    using (PpjSteContainer _context = new PpjSteContainer() )
    {
        return _context.ParentSet.Include("Child").Single(x => x.Id == Id);
    }
```

**Problem:**

If I now run this project (the Service1.svc is start page), VS2010 automatically generates the test client to invoke the service. But once I invoke the service, I get an StackOverflowException! Debugging on the server side looks ok until it returns the object graph.

If I remove the **Include("Child")** everything is ok, but of course the *Child* objects are missing now.
I have no idea what I'm missing. I read a lot of howto's and guides, but all do it the way I did it (at least that's what I think)...
I tried the School example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789839.aspx), but this does not work for me as it seems the database generation and the coding in the example does not match.

So, I would much appreciate if someone could guide me how to make this work.

**P.S.**

- Yes, all Entity-Classes are marked "[DataContract(IsReference = true)]"
- Lazy-Loading is set to "false" in the edmx file

**Edit:**
I changed the WCF to be hosted in a console app and no longer in IIS. Of course then I had to write my own little test client.
Funny enough, now everything's working.
I of course have no idea why, but at least for my testing this is a solution...

Comment: did you solve that problem? I have it now... please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150920/preventing-stackoverflowexception-while-serializing-ef-object-graph-into-json

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](http://devblog.petrellyn.com/?p=278). Basically you have to make the serializer aware of cycles in the navigation properties.

Comment: I've never had to do that. I experienced cyclic references / stack overflow errors only when serializing with JSON. I created my own json processor to use JSON.NET which supports cyclic references and object identities.  For xml, use DataContractSerializer and set [DataContract(IsReference = true)] like stated in the post.

Comment: Although it sound as if cyclic references would be the problem, I don't think the above article is still valid for EF4 and STE? Especially because of the fact that if WCF is hosted on console-app, everything is fine even without a custom attribute, I assume that this is a configuration problem? (pls. see my edit)